Anki Add-on: Custom Fullscreen Toggle Button Not Executing Function
I’ve been working on an Anki add-on to add a custom fullscreen toggle button to the top toolbar. I’ve managed to get the button to display, but the bridge command doesn’t seem to be working, and the toggle_fullscreen function is not being executed.
Here is my current code:
from aqt import mw
from aqt.qt import *
from aqt import gui_hooks

def toggle_fullscreen():
    if mw.isFullScreen():
        mw.showNormal()
    else:
        mw.showFullScreen()

def add_fullscreen_button(links, toolbar):
    button_html = """
    <button id="fullscreen-button" onclick="pycmd('toggle_fullscreen');">Fullscreen Mode</button>
    """
    links.append(button_html)

def on_bridge_cmd(cmd):
    if cmd == "toggle_fullscreen":
        toggle_fullscreen()

def init_addon():
    gui_hooks.top_toolbar_did_init_links.append(add_fullscreen_button)
    mw.web.set_bridge_command(on_bridge_cmd, "custom_toggle_fullscreen")

init_addon()


Despite the button appearing correctly, clicking it does not seem to trigger the toggle_fullscreen function.
Does anyone know what might be going wrong? Why isn’t the toggle_fullscreen function being executed when I click the button?
Thanks in advance!
Edit:
I think I’ve found a somewhat working code.
It's not perfect as the fullscreen mode is not entirely what you'd expect. It's fullscreen but sometimes you still see the menu bar.
This is the code:
from aqt import mw
from aqt.qt import *
from aqt import gui_hooks

def toggle_fullscreen():
    if mw.isFullScreen():
        mw.showNormal()
    else:
        mw.showFullScreen()

def add_fullscreen_button(links, toolbar):
    button_html = """
    <button onclick="pycmd('toggle_fullscreen');">Fullscreen Mode</button>
    """
    links.append(button_html)

def on_js_message(handled, message, context):
    if message == "toggle_fullscreen":
        toggle_fullscreen()
        return True, False  
    return handled

def init_addon():
    gui_hooks.top_toolbar_did_init_links.append(add_fullscreen_button)
    gui_hooks.webview_did_receive_js_message.append(on_js_message)

init_addon()


